# How to use both web and api authenthicators in a project

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've already developed an API which uses passport authentication, it's used on a react-native app.

Now I have to develop some web-functions to an Admin user, I've made an Admin model and migration, but I don't know how to enable web authentication to the Admin model only. I've looking for some tutorials but all I've found is about laravel default authentication and I've used the User model for the passport auth.

Please help me!!

Comment: You should add what you have done till now or what you have already found so that others may help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an Admin model, you can create a column inside the users tables, call it account type. Then in your Laravel code, you could do something like

```
if (Auth::user()->account_type === 'admin') {
  // your code.
}
```

In your API or WEB, you would simply check for multiple types and route accordingly

In blade syntax (for your front end)

```
@if ( {{Auth::user()->account_type}} === 'admin')

@else  

@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to approach this.

1 - If you have just a couple admin users, you could write add them as regular users using the default authentication stuff and add a route middleware that runs after the auth middleware. 
Code for this:

```
//Create this at app/Http/Middleware/Admin.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

class Admin
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $admins = [1,32,23];//place your admins IDs here
        //I've hardcoded the admin ids, but you can also check them from a table Admins::all() or column such as auth()->user()->is_admin
        if(!in_array(auth()->user()->id,$admins))
            return throw new AuthenticationException('You are not allowed here');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

then add the middleware declaration to the app/Http/Kernel.php in the $routeMiddleware .

```
'admin' => App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
```

And use it on you admin routes

```
Route::middleware(['auth','admin'])->group(function () {
    //admin routes here
}
```

2 - You can also replace all the authentication steps to use a custom model, I've done this once or twice, but that has so many side effects that is simply not worth it. But if you choose to do so, you can start by extending your admin class with Authenticable

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

Then you'd have to go and also duplicate all the files under app/Http/Auth, override a bunch of stuff in order to use your custom class, then duplicate all the views in order to have a login, reset password and other stuff.

Trust me, not worth it. I'd go with option one.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a pretty wise solution, but there isn't problem if I have User authenticated by passport?

Comment: Not at all. Laravel is pretty smar and builds all on top of existing code. It all boils down to a couple traits inside the user model. But it's still using the user model.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this comment in a Laravel Echo issue, but couldn't replicate it at all.
What I tried is creating a new Middleware called Broadcast and do this accordingly:
    class BroadcastMiddleware() {

```
public function handle() {
$web = Auth::guard('web')->user();
if ($web) {
    return response()->json($web);
}

$api = Auth::guard('api')->user();
if ($api) {
    return response()->json($api);
}
return response()->json('Unauthorized.', 500);
}}
```

And also tried setting up a route for /broadcast/auth

```
Route::post('/realtime/auth', function(){
return true;
})->middleware('broadcast');
```

However, using above code, it's returning User model; however instead Laravel's broadcasting/auth return something like: auth:"374f7ff42b7da877aa35:c29addedec281b418331a61dc3cfc74da8b108222565fa4924a8..."

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and also tried a few different ways but this way seemed to work out the best.  You can check out the tutorial here:

https://medium.com/employbl/easily-build-administrator-login-into-a-laravel-5-app-8a942e4fef37

After I did that, it was easy to figure out how to make registrations have to be approved by admins first as well. Also, you should follow the author of this tutorial - he has a bunch of good stuff!